# Can not run ack after installing it using MacPorts

Tags: mac, macports, package-management

After installing p5-app-ack using Macports I can see it is installed correctly.
[image]

I can not run it however.
I get `ack: command not found.`
and `which ack` displays nothing.
How can I see where port installed my ack and how to add it to the executalble PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacPorts, by default, installs into `/opt/local/`, judging by the screen shot ack should be in `/opt/local/perl/p5-app-ack/` if you used the default install path. Make sure that path is in your $PATH environment variable.

To add it to your path edit your shell config file (probably ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc) and add or modify the following line.
`export PATH="$PATH":/opt/local/perl/p5-app-ack`

I don't use MacPorts for ack, I install it manually with the following command from the [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/install/) install page.

`curl http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3`

This will install [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/install/) into the `$HOME/bin/` folder as a single large perl file and I did not have to modify my $PATH variable.

Comment: I see it in: /opt/local/libexec/perl5.12. Is it correct install location for binary?

Comment: And I get: export $PATH='$PATH':/opt/local/libexec/perl5.12
-bash: export: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin=$PATH:/opt/local/libexec/perl5.12': not a valid identifier when I try to export

Comment: It is 'export PATH...` Leave off the "$" Sorry about that. I fixed the post.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up copying ack executable to the /opt/local/bin anyway.

Comment: fwiw brew seems to do a better job at ensuring all binaries are symlinked to /usr/local/bin.  I ran into so many issues like this using ports that I just gave up and went to brew.